# How to automate a chat application using Selenium/Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, chat

I have a task for automating a chat application.I am using Webdriver along with Java. Two different users will login simultaneously on two different browsers and initiate chat. I would appreciate if anybody can provide me some suggestions.

Comment: What is it you want to automate in the app? Can you provide the URL...

Comment: Hi Vinay,  I am extremely sorry as i cannot provide you the URL as it is highly confidential for our firm. For example just take an example of gtalk chat app. I need to automate the way two users will be using it.

Answer (score 7):

You've got two concerns to worry about.  The first is making sure you've different browsers for each user, and the second is running the two users concurrently.  There are a couple of different ways to do each of them, so I'll look at them separately.

## Managing two browsers

The first part, that of opening two browsers, isn't too difficult;  You can just create a separate WebDriver object for each one.  You may have to use two different browsers, however, to avoid any kind of session sharing issues:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

WebDriver user_1 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver user_2 = new ChromeDriver();
```

If you need to open two instances of the same browser, your best option is to use [Selenium Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) to host your desired browsers, and then creating remote connections to them:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
URL server = new URL("http://your-server-location.com");
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capabilities);
```

If you don't want to set up your own Selenium Grid, you can use a service like [Sauce Labs](http://saucelabs.com/) to manage it for you (and also give you an easy way to add extra test platform resources).

## Managing two users simultaneously

It sounds like you can just have the one test class performing each action in turn against the relevant Webdriver.  Use something like the [Page Object Model](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) to provide service objects representing your pages, which you can pass an instance of WebDriver too.  Then, you can express your test logic more fluently rather then dealing with different webdrivers and elements:

```
public class Chatsite{
  public WebDriver driver;
  private WebElement talkbox;
  private WebElement chatlog;
  private WebElement sendbutton;

  public Chatsite(WebDriver passed_in_driver){
      driver = passed_in_driver;
      talkbox = driver.find_element("name", "talkbox");
      sendbutton = driver.find_element("name", "send");
      chatlog = driver.find_element("name", "chatlog");
      driver.get("http://www.yoursite.com");
  }

  public void say(String string_to_type){
      talkbox.send_keys(string_to_type);
      sendbutton.click();
  }

  public void sees_in_the_chatlog(String expected_content){
      String current_chat_text =  chatlog.getText();
      assertTrue("Couldn't find content", current_chat_text.contains(expected_content));
  }
}

#Now, in your tests
#Name your users so it's easier to keep track of them
Chatsite david = Chatsite.new(user_1);
Chatsite susan = Chatsite.new(user_2);

david.say("Isn't it a fine day?");
susan.sees_in_the_chatlog("Isn't it a fine day?");

susan.say("If you're going to talk about the weather I'm failing this test case");
## And so on in that fashion
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm working on it. However the two chat windows are opening as a different web window, and I am unable to select the window of second user and hence unable to assert the arrival of message there. Any Help?

Comment: Are you using two different WebDriver objects for the windows?

Comment: @DylanLacey I tried option Managing 2 browser and written code below. But only last browser(FF) opening with url while first (Chrome) is opening but not dealing with url. strange is that Chrome browser object is working in assertion that i did for FF. Not sure how. Could you please help? Here is code.   ` self.driver = launchApplication.driver_initialized(browser=run_browser)
        self.driver_ff = launchApplication.driver_initialized(browser=run_ff_browser)
        
        # Opening 2 browsers
        self.driver.get(run_server)        
        self.driver_ff.get(run_server)`

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have to test it on same browser, then refer to this post on how to open multiple browser windows for testing - [How to switch instances in WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855406/how-to-switch-instances-in-webdriver/17855545#17855545).

Comment: Is it working any sample code?,i have same situation to test an chat application.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily automate the chat application by using playwright + javascript/typescript. Im using more than 10 browser instance at a time to handle different users. its very easy to handle different users in same browser type[10 chrome browser can load an handle] with multiple browser context.